# "cannot find EFI directory" Error while installing grub

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, grub, bootloader

##### What I Have Done?

I'm planning to replace the current default volume with a new one for some reason, so that's why I'm planning to copy data to it, set up grub, and replace the original volume with this new volume.

In the existing Ubuntu server, Attached additional volume (newly formatted volume), setting up grub for this.

After that, I get the below error while installing grub.

##### Command

```
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/new-volume/ --force /dev/nvme1n1
```

##### Output

```
Installing for arm64-efi platform.
grub-install: error: cannot find EFI directory
```

Any idea on how to resolve this?